# Node/express application failing to connect to Mongodb Atlas using mongoose

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express, mongoose, mongodb-atlas

I have a node/express application that I am trying to connect to Mongodb Atlas using mongoose.

All of my code is identical to a previous app that I had connect to Atlas (which worked fine). When I run it on my work machine (Windows 10) everything works as expected. However, when I run it on my MacBook Pro (Mojave), the express app runs but the mongoose connection to Atlas throws the following error:

```
{ Error: queryTxt EBADNAME development-zv5hp.mongodb.net
    at QueryReqWrap.onresolve [as oncomplete] (dns.js:196:19)
  errno: 'EBADNAME',
  code: 'EBADNAME',
  syscall: 'queryTxt',
  hostname: 'development-zv5hp.mongodb.net' }
```

**server.js**

```
const express = require('express');
const mongoose = require('mongoose');

const app = express();

mongoose
  .connect(
    'mongodb+srv://client:<PASSWORD>@development-zv5hp.mongodb.net/shop',
    { useNewUrlParser: true }
  )
  .then(() => console.log('MongoDB Connected...'))
  .catch(err => console.log(err));

const PORT = process.env.PORT || 5000;
app.listen(PORT, () => console.log(`Server running on port ${PORT}`));
```

What might be causing this issue?
I have checked the Atlas user and password and have whitelisted my IP (in fact whitelisted all IPs)

Using:

- node v10.15.3
- express v4.16.4
- mongoose v5.5.1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using Google's DNS server `8.8.8.8` and `8.8.4.4` can resolve this issue

Comment: This worked - Thanks. Obviously something with my home ISP that was blocking it. Interestingly, if I tethered to my phone to use mobile data (provided by the same ISP) it worked with the default DNS...

Answer (score 0):

please add autoIndex: false its working for me

```
mongoose
  .connect(
    'mongodb+srv://client:<PASSWORD>@development-zv5hp.mongodb.net/shop',
    {autoIndex: false, useNewUrlParser: true }
```

Comment: Unfortunately this made no difference. Still throwing the same error.

Answer (score 0):

This error is caused because the URI `'mongodb+srv://client:<PASSWORD>@development-zv5hp.mongodb.net/shop'` that was passed to connect was unable to be resolved. Your DNS server does not know it and thus cannot resolve an IP. Hence ebadname.

[change this like Addison mentioned](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Nu2D8.png)